# Python Hypothesis testing: Is there a way to avoid drawing a LazyStrategy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, lazy-evaluation, python-hypothesis

If Python [hypothesis](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) strategies are too deeply nested, using `draw` will not create an actual example, but a `LazyStrategy`. This can be quite problematic at times because the resulting object behaves very differently from an actual example.

Is there a way to enforce eager evaluations of strategies, such that calling `draw` always returns an actual example of the corresponding strategy?

For example:

```
from hypothesis import strategies as st

@st.composite
def my_composite_strategy(draw):
    some_example = draw(some_very_complex_deeply_nested_strategy)
    print(type(some_example))
    ...
```

Will print `<class 'hypothesis.strategies._internal.lazy.LazyStrategy'>` if executed. What I want instead is `<class 'my_module.MyObjectIWriteAStrategyFor'>`, so I can use `some_example` really as if it was a real object.

Comment: Ah maybe the reason is that somehwere int he `some_very_complex_deeply_nested_strategy` in a `composite` instead of an example an `st:builds` is returned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis/issues/3224, your `some_very_complex_deeply_nested_strategy` is returning a strategy rather than the object you want

Comment: Well yes, thanks for citing me^^